# How to fix "No module named RPi" ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

When i try to run it this is the response I get:

```
File "C:/Users/jb/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/GUI Automationmfana.py", line 6, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
```

Comment: Presumably `RPi` is a module only available on a Raspberry Pi python distribution to control the GPIO pins. What do you expect it to do on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pip3 install RPi.GPIO`  or for `env` `pip install RPi.GPIO`

As for me I used this  for `RPi` 4B `sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpi`